# Installing android automotive OS onto regular android tablet device?

Tags: android-automotive

are there any ways for installing the android automotive os onto a regular android tablet for debugging purposes? As far as I could see, I can only use the emulator inside Android Studio for debugging. 
But I want to debug on a physical device (as good as possible).

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not possible and likely will be that way for now. Android Automotive OS is designed to run in a vehicle, there is no incentive or need for tablet makers to create a version of Andriod Automotive OS for their tablet. If you want a physical device, there are automotive reference boards by various CPU manufacturers that support Android Automotive OS but likely it will cost a lot more than a tablet and would require a lot more work to maintain and be less stable compared to a commercial device.

There might be an option of using Pixel 3XL for app development although I have not tried so do not now how well it works. You can find more information in Google website: https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/pixel3